# Explain current flow direction with red-lined and without red-lined

Tags: current

Can you tell how the current is flowing from the battery switch (with the red-lined section) and then without the red-lined.

Without red-line: from the battery switch through the bus bar, then thrcircuit breaker (5A,) then the surge supressor and relay.

With red-line: From the battery dwitch through the surge supressor, then the relay and then through the circuit breaker (3A)?

[image]